# Multiple content presenters in window style breaks design time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, window

i have custom base window class with style (and template) overridden, if template contains only 1 ContentPresenter (with ContentSource="Content") - it displays fine in designer, but if i add more ContentPresenters (with ContentSources set to dependency properties in custom window base class) - it still compiles and works fine, but no longer displays this custom style in designer with error in template that it can't find CustomWindowBase type in TargetType field of ControlTemplate, here is the reproducible example:

CustomWindowBase.cs:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfTest
{
    public class CustomWindowBase : Window
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Header", typeof(object), typeof(CustomWindowBase));
        public object Header
        {
            get => GetValue(HeaderProperty);
            set => SetValue(HeaderProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty FooterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Footer", typeof(object), typeof(CustomWindowBase));
        public object Footer
        {
            get => GetValue(FooterProperty);
            set => SetValue(FooterProperty, value);
        }

        static CustomWindowBase()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomWindowBase), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomWindowBase)));
        }
    }
}
```

WindowStyle.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns:this="clr-namespace:WpfTest"
                    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style x:Key="CustomWindow" TargetType="this:CustomWindowBase">
        <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None"/>
        <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="CanResizeWithGrip"/>
        <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="CanResizeWithGrip"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF202020"/>
        <Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
            <Setter.Value>
                <WindowChrome CornerRadius="0" NonClientFrameEdges="None" GlassFrameThickness="0" ResizeBorderThickness="7" CaptionHeight="32"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type this:CustomWindowBase}">
                    <Grid Background="#FF202020">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="32"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <!--<ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" ClipToBounds="True"/>-->
                        <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Content" Grid.Row="1" ClipToBounds="True"/>
                        <!--<ContentPresenter ContentSource="Footer" Grid.Row="2" ClipToBounds="True"/>-->
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : CustomWindowBase
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<local:CustomWindowBase x:Class="WpfTest.MainWindow"
                        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTest"
                        mc:Ignorable="d"
                        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
                        Style="{StaticResource CustomWindow}">
    <local:CustomWindowBase.Header>
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="SomeText" Foreground="White" FontSize="12"/>
    </local:CustomWindowBase.Header>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="SomeText" Foreground="White" FontSize="40"/>
    <local:CustomWindowBase.Footer>
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="SomeText" Foreground="White" FontSize="12"/>
    </local:CustomWindowBase.Footer>
</local:CustomWindowBase>
```

App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfTest.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTest"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="WindowStyle.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

this displays fine both in runtime and designer, but if you uncomment two ContentPresenters in WindowStyle.xaml - it no longer works in designer, any ideas how to fix this?

.NET 7, Visual Studio 2022

Answer (score 0):

When you override the `FrameworkElement.DefaultStyleKey` property then this means that you effectively change the required target type of the default `Style`.
You *must* define a valid default `Style`.

To be valid, such a `Style` must

1. be implicit (no explicit resource key) ❌
2. be located in the *Generic.xaml* file
   (inside a folder named *Themes* folder in the project root) ❌
3. have a `Style.TargetType` value that matches the `Type` of the `FrameworkElement.DefaultStyleKey` property value ✔️

This means:

1. Remove the `x:Key` from your default `Style`
2. Move the default `Style` to the *Generic.xaml* file (or merge the *WindowStyle.xaml* into the *Generic.xaml* dictionary) and

   - remove the merged dictionary from the *App.xaml* file
   - remove the local `CustomWindowBase.Style` attribute assignment from the `CustomWindowBase` root element (in *MainWindow.xaml*)

Comment: tried it, now my MainWindow in designer has default style (not my custom style) with plain white content background and in runtime it also has default style, but with plain black content background, so both is incorrect, no design-time errors this time tho, commenting or uncommenting ContentPresenters does nothing

Comment: Quick google said i have to put Generic.xaml into Themes folder, tried it, now the style applies at runtime, but still does not in design time

Comment: In your template you set the background of the root container to black (#FF202020). That's why the window has a black background. It's working. When you set the color to red the background will be red proofing that the style is correctly referenced and template is correctly applied.

Comment: You very likely want to bind the Grid.Background to the templated parent's `Window.Background` property: `<Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"><Grid>`.

Comment: The default style (Generic.xaml resources or themes in general) is resolved at runtime. That's why the designer shows an intermediate style.

Comment: it didn't help, i usually check the header of window in designer, this custom testing style does not have anything to display the title or any buttons, just plain grid, but MainWindow.xaml in designer has both title and buttons, so the style is not applied

Comment: is it possible to make it show-up in design time? that's the whole point, i want to see my custom window style in design time :D

Comment: No. The XAML designer is only creating fakes. For example, the constructor of the types is never called. You can try Blend. But I assume it behaves the same (I'm not using Blend). I'm afraid you have to run your application in order to design the main window. The XAML designer is a very light weight editor to help to arrange elements, setup bindings and modify the layout. It's not a virtual runtime.

Comment: @Notrum666 When you execute your application in debug mode you can modify the style of a control live (thanks to hot reload). In addition, there is a live preview pane for the GUI in Visual Studio (not the XAML the designer) to enable you to stay in the IDE while programming the layout, a live tree inspector and a live property inspector. In debug mode you have full runtime support.